# What is a non-local particle in condensed matter physics?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, quantum-spin

What exactly is "non-local" in physics? How can a particle be non-local particle? Are non-local particles and collective modes related with each other? Are solitons local or non-local? (I am asking in context of quantum spin liquids)

Comment: Page 9 in the review paper [Quantum spin liquids](https://arxiv.org/abs/1601.03742) says "Some elementary excitations are `non-local', in that they cannot be created individually by any set of local operators". Is this what the question is about?

Comment: Yes. This is exactly what I am trying to understand. "Local operators" what are they?

Comment: Local operators are operators that act non trivially only on a few adjacent sites of the lattice and act as  identities on all other sites. Think of spin-spin coupling terms in the Hamiltonians of Ising or Heisenberg models.